# Async CTP: Does Task.Factory.StartNew uses IO completion thread?

Tags: c#, wcf

I am using Async CTP and written some WCF service operation code like this.

```
    public async Task<string> GetDetailsfromDatabase(string name)
    {
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            return CallDatabaseandGetDetails(name);
        });
    }
```

Calling StartNew uses a thread pool thread to go and get the data from the database. Does the thread get blocked while the db operation is running OR it used IO completion thread?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF Async Operation + IO Operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409092/wcf-async-operation-io-operation)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice (or two "almost" same questions)

Comment: Also, with the async CTP this will not work in WCF; only with the VS 2011 / .Net FX 4.5 developer preview that the Task support for operations will work in WCF.

Comment: Sure. With .NEt FX 4.5 does the above code makes use of a the IO completion so the thread gets blocked waiting for IO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `TaskFactory.FromAsync` method:

Example:

http://mstecharchitect.blogspot.com/2011/02/parallel-programming-net-40-ivusing.html

Regards.